# How to apply boundary conditions to the general solution of heat equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

The general solution of the heat equation in a slab of finite length $L$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \kappa \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}$$

is

$$u(x,t) = A_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n \exp\left(\frac{n^2\pi^2\kappa t}{L}\right)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$$

For

$$u(x,0)=f(x)=A_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n \cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$$

How should we apply the following boundary conditions:

$$\frac{\partial u(0,t)}{\partial x} = C$$
$$\frac{\partial u(L,t)}{\partial x} = 0$$
$$ u(x,0) = T$$

to solve $u(x,t)$? $T$ is the initial temperature in the slab. $x=L$ end is insulated and a constant flux is applied at $x=0$.

Comment: The cosine series for $x$ does not satisfy the boundary condition $u_t(0,x) = C$ unless $C=0$

Comment: @Dylan This the classic Neumann boundary condition. You mean the PDE cannot be solved under Neumann boundary condition?

Comment: Neumann boundary condition is $u_x(0,t) = 0$. This problem has $u_x(0,t) = C$

Comment: $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = -\frac{n\pi}{L}\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n\sin \left(\frac{n\pi x}{L} \right)$$

which is $0$ at $x=0$